# how to wait for data to download in tws api from interactive brokers?

Tags: python, api, interactive-brokers

I'm drafting an application in python to interact with tws api, aka ibapi.

in a triggered position() event, I'm calling ContractDetails, and do receive it's data events. at it's end event, I'm setting self. contract_details_received = 1.

a decent event driven program should probably trigger the waiting code itself at the contractdetailsend event, but for now I'd like to wait for this flag in some loop before carrying on.

however the flag is being raised at the contractdetailsend event, the loop continues to wait, since it does probably not detect the flag.

could you help with an advice?

thanks in advance,
alex

Comment: It does not make sense. I'm using a similar setup with a flag set at contractDetailsEnd and it's working exactly as it should. Review your code.

Comment: contractDetailsEnd event and my waiting code happen in different threads, that's why the waiting loop is missing the event.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to loop waiting for things to happen, by using thread locks.

definitely, the best way to go is to use the events to trigger the behaviour.